# Evaluate a Double Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dy\,dx$$

*Sorry if the formatting is off*

Is there a way to evaluate without using polar coordinates or is that the only way to integrate this?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with using polar coordinates? It makes this integral much easier.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with polar coordinates. I was just curious as to whether or not there was a way to evaluate it without using polar coordinates as the questions just states evaluate. But thank you for your help

Comment: No:  the function $e^{-x^2}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative, anything you do involves shifting coordinates:  keeping the standard ones will not yield the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use infinite series, and then try to determine the value to which the resulting series converges...

In all seriousness, because of the "$e^{x^2+y^2}$," I don't think you're going to get much better than polar.  Recall that $e^{x^2}$ does not have an elementary anti-derivative.  Perhaps an elliptical transformation (e.g. with the Jacobian) would work, but I'll lump that in the same category as polar.

tl;dr: Probably not--polar is your best bet.

Comment: One last question, what happens to my limits when I convert to polar coordinates? More specificially, the sqrt{1-x^2} upper bound is causing me some confusion

Comment: @Coop $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the top half of a circle of radius $1$.  Your region only covers the part in Quadrant I.

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha! I was going to save this for a personal message but I have no clue how to do that. I just wanted to thank you for all of your help with my questions! :)

Comment: @Coop My pleasure. :)  (And, for what it's worth, there is no private message feature on StackExchange.)

Comment: So my integral becomes $$\int_0^{pi}\int_0^1 re^{-r^2}\,dr\,dtheta$$ right?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 e^{-r^2} r\,dr\,d\theta$, with $\pi/2$, not $\pi$. ${}\qquad{}$